# How to convert matlab table [Inf], '' entry to char string

Tags: string, matlab, type-conversion, data-conversion, matlab-table

I have a Matlab table and want to create an SQL INSERT statement of this line(s).

```
K>> obj.ConditionTable

obj.ConditionTable = 

      Name              Data            Category         Description
________________    ____________    _________________    ___________

'Layout'            'STR'           ''                   ''         
'Radius'            [       Inf]    'Radius_2000_inf'    ''         
'aq'                [         0]    '0'                  ''         
'VehicleSpeed'      [       200]    'Speed_160_230'      ''
```

Erros when conditionTable = obj.ConditionTable(1,:);

```
K>> char(conditionTable.Data)
Error using char
Cell elements must be character arrays.

K>> char(conditionTable.Description)    
ans =    
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

1. problem: the [Inf] entry
2. problem: possibly [123] number entries
3. problem: '' entries

Additionally, following commands are also useless in this matter:

```
K>> length(conditionTable.Data)    
ans =    
     1

K>> isempty(conditionTable.Description)    
ans =    
     0
```

**Target Statement** would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `ConditionTable` (`Name`, `Data`, `Category`, `Description`, `etfmiso_id`) VALUES ("Layout", "STR", "", "", 618);
```

Comment: is the inf entry contained in a vector? Have you tried mat2str?

Comment: gives me: Error using mat2str (line 55)
Input matrix must be numeric.

Comment: what about `str2double`

Comment: str2double(conditionTable.Data) gives me: ans = NaN for [Inf]

Comment: can you add the table as data please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `num2str` accept a single variable of any type and will return a string, so all these operations are valid:

```
>> num2str('123')
ans =
123
>> num2str('chop')
ans =
chop
>> num2str(Inf)
ans =
Inf
```

However, it can deal with purely *numeric* arrays (e.g. `num2str([5 456])` is also valid), but it will bomb out if you try to throw a cell array at it (even if all your cells are numeric).

---

There are 2 possible way to work around that to convert all your values to character arrays:

**1) use an intermediate cell array**
I recreated a table [`T`] with the same data than in your example. Then running:

```
%% Intermediate Cell array
T3 = cell2table( cellfun( @num2str , table2cell(T) , 'uni',0) ) ;
T3.Properties.VariableNames = T.Properties.VariableNames 
T3 = 
         Name         Data         Category         Description
    ______________    _____    _________________    ___________
    'Layout'          'STR'    ''                   ''         
    'Radius'          'Inf'    'Radius_2000_inf'    ''         
    'aq'              '0'      '0'                  ''         
    'VehicleSpeed'    '200'    'Speed_160_230'      ''
```

produces a new table containing only strings. Notice that we had to recreate the column names (copied from the initial table), as these are not transferred into the cell array during conversion.
These method is suitable for relatively small tables, as the round trip table/cellarray/table plus the call to `cellfun` will probably be quite slow for larger tables.

---

**2) Use [`varfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html) function**

`varfun` is for Tables the equivalent of `cellfun` for cell arrays. You'd think that a simple

```
T2 = varfun( @num2str , T )
```

would do the job then ... well no. This will error too. If you look at the `varfun` code at  the line indicated by the error, you'll notice that internally, data in your table are converted to cell arrays and the function is applied to that. As we saw above, `num2str` errors when met with a cell array. The trick to overcome that, is to send a customised version of `num2str` which will accept cell arrays. For example:

```
cellnum2str = @(x) cellfun(@num2str,x,'uni',0)
```

Armed with that, you can now use it to convert your table:

```
%% Use "varfun"
cellnum2str = @(x) cellfun(@num2str,x,'uni',0) ;
T2 = varfun( cellnum2str , T ) ;
T2.Properties.VariableNames = T.Properties.VariableNames ;
```

This will produce the same table than in the example 1 above. Notice that again we had to reassign the column headers on the newly created table (*the irony is `varfun` choked trying to apply the function on the column headers, but does not re-use or return them in the output ... go figure.*)

---

discussion: Initially I tried to make the `varfun` solution work (hence the `T2` name of the result), and wanted to recommend this one, because I didn't like the table/cell/table conversion of the other solution. Now I have seen what goes on into `varfun`, I am not so sure that this solution will be faster. It might be slightly more readable in a semantic way, but if speed is a concern you'll have to try both version and choose which one gives you the best results.

Answer (score 0):

for the record: num2str(cell2mat(conditionTable.Data)), works, independant if 'abc', [Inf], [0], [123.123], apparently..